# Why isn't my two station complex showing "Profitability" as a graph choice like the invidivual stations did?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I am playing X3-AP.  I had two factories making Hornet and Mosquito missiles in Queen's Harbour.  They were both doing brisk business but I decided to pool their resources by turning them into a complex.  I towed the Mosquito factory over to the Hornet factory and placed a Complex Construction Kit between them.  I see the resulting combined station on my report and, from watching it's cash flow, it's doing great.

However, when I select Advanced -> Graphs for the Complex, there's only one choice: Stock.  None of the other choices (especially Station Profitability) even appear.

How did this happen?  Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: neat, I never knew about the graphs, that's something interesting to try once I get home...  I wonder how my weed complex is doing

Comment: Yes, they're very handy for determining whether you have a viable station setup as-is or whether it's worth it to build a raw material supplier as a part of the chain.  In a lot of Teladi space, it's not worth building a self-sufficient weed complex.  You can just as easily get a lot of the material from the nearby Teladi weed-fiends.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was impatient.  After several game hours, the "Station Profitability" graph was again available as a choice.